# Reverse geocoding in angular google maps

Tags: angular, reverse-geocoding, angular-google-maps

```
getAddress( lat: number, lng: number ) {
    console.log('Finding Address');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      let request = { latLng: latlng };
      geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          let result = results[0];
          let rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
          let resultLength = rsltAdrComponent.length;
          if (result != null) {
            this.address = rsltAdrComponent[resultLength - 8].short_name;
          } else {
            alert('No address available!');
          }
        }
      });
  }
  }
```

I am trying to use reverse geocoding in my angular 4 application. I am using agm for integrating google map with the angular app.

Declared google variable in *.ts as follows

```
declare let google: any;
```

But when I am using I am getting the error as follows,

> ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Here is the component.ts

```
declare let google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-find-cycle',
  templateUrl: './cmp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmp.component.scss']
})

export class Cmp {
}
```

Comment: Hope you have declared declare let google: any; above component decorator?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Included the google maps api right.?

Comment: you need to use the map loaded function, and call getAddress() in there, google is not loaded before

Comment: @Ruben, Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: @FranklinPious, As I have integrated via AGM (https://angular-maps.com/) , I think this is enough. Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: @Anil yes that is enough, you don't have to include google maps api yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

execute getAddress() after the map is loaded:

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="mapReady()" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="styles">

mapReady() {
    this.getAddress(...);
}
```

or add `private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,` to your constructor do this

```
 this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I was missing the loading of agm-map into my component.